# How do you assert something is not true in Python?

Tags: python, assert

In trying to understand `assert` in Python, specifically inverting it, I came up with this...

```
>>> assert != ( 5 > 2 )
>>> assert != ( 2 > 5 )
```

Now the first line fails and the second passes. What's the idiomatic way to assert something is false?

Comment: Careful using parentheses with `assert`, as it may lead to surprising results. `assert a > 0, "expected positive value"` has different behavior from `assert(a > 0, "expected positive value")`. (the second one always passes even when it shouldn't)

Comment: WTF?! Why the down arrows? Didn't mean to bug ya, but I thought that this was the place to ask questions.

Comment: Kevin, thanks. I copied the link example and did not know that. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: I edited your question. Try and ask generic questions lots of people will come across. New programmers still just want to read a question answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You'd use the [boolean `not` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), not the `!=` inequality comparison operator:

```
>>> assert not (5 > 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> assert not (2 > 5)
```

An `assert` passes if the test is true in the boolean sense, so you need to use the boolean `not` operator to invert the test.